# Javascript local scoped variable names

Tags: javascript

While using variables internal to a function I often use smaller keywords, e.g.:

```
function (descriptiveParameterArray) {
    var inArr = descriptiveParameter;
    var frstVal = inArr[0];
    var secVal = inArr[1];
}
```

But some approaches might suggest that var names should be more descriptive.
What is the best practice in this regard?

Comment: just use a smaller parameter name

Comment: *"What is the best practice in this regard?"* Somebody who reads your code should be able to understand it. The "size" of a variable is irrelevant. But if you use cryptic variable names then they might not understand it.

Comment: `function ([firstValue, secondValue]){ ... win ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use descriptive variable names wherever you can, no matter whether you're in a function you consider to be self-contained or not. Maybe a good name for them would be `xCoord` and `yCoord`. Maybe `key` and `value`. Maybe `name` and `age` - and so on. There's no correct *generic* answer for what they should be named, just that they *should* be named descriptively. (The variable name doesn't have to be long as long as there's no ambiguity or vagueness)